# Where does npm store node modules?

Tags: node.js, npm

I just setup official node.js on windows which includes npm in custom directory d:\myserver\nodejs

I tested npm with

```
npm install less
```

it works but I can't see any less directory in node_modules\npm\node_modules subdirectory.

Where could I find it (I guess the name of less module is actually less).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

under : node_modules

just check where you where pointer "in what directory were you" at the time of the installation

d:\myserver\nodejs -> node_modules

Comment: I was launching npm from c:\ command prompt :( can I just delete c:\node_modules and retart again without messing anything ?

Comment: yeah, just ,make sure to be in the right directory when installing "cd /path_to_project/nodejs" :)

Answer (score 1):

Just for further clarification, google brought me here while looking up where global modules are stored (installed via `npm install -g ...`).

From the [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders)

> - Local install (default): puts stuff in ./node_modules of the current package root.
> - Global install (with -g): puts stuff in /usr/local or wherever node is installed.
> - Install it locally if you’re going to require() it.
> - Install it globally if you’re going to run it on the command line.
> - If you need both, then install it in both places, or use npm link.